# Работа кулера от зарядного устройства

Tags: железо

Имеется кулер стремя проводками - черный, красный и желтый. Имеется зарядное устройство выдающее 12V. Как только не пытался подключать проводки - толку ноль. Насколько я понимаю - красный и желтый - это +, черный - это -. Или может быть не хватает силы электрического тока? Возможно есть какие то нюансы или опыт - буду рад помощи.

Comment: @deeplulz, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1]  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Qe5BY.png(взято из ответа @shaman888)

Comment: Может зарядное слишком "умное"?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что проблемы с железом не являются допустимой темой Stackoverflow на русском языке.

Comment: @decyrus, ты все 40 вопросов с этой меткой что ли на закрытие отправил?

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет только часть. Эту тему из всех можно с трудом притянуть к настройке серверного оборудования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверить кулер сначала. А вообще, если не ошибаюсь в компе БП импульсный. А зарядное какое?

Answer (score 0):

Всё почти правильно.

Красный - это, традиционно, "+", черный, не менее традиционно, "-".

Третий провод обычно используется для определения скорости вращения (если мне не изменяет память...). Если ОЧЕНЬ интересно - скину линк на интересный документ как раз про кулеры.

P.S. А блок питания рабочий? А кулер прозванивали? КЗ или обрыв не показывает?;)

Answer (score 0):

Желтый провод это второй плюс, сделан для регулировки оборотов кулера.

На самом кулере(на наклейке)может быть написана характеристика, вольтаж и сила тока.

Посмотри.

Если бы кулеру не хватало питания он бы крутился, но медленно, скорей всего ты его уже спалил)

Comment: ... так же бывали озвучены варианты про датчик температуры в самом кулере и многие другие...Лично я склонен считать, что в трех-пиновом варианте регулировка оборотов достигается изменением напряжения. В четырех-пиновом - там да, четвертый провод как раз и используется для [ШИМ (или PWM по буржуйски)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%98%D0%9C).